# Can が be interchanged with を？

Tags: grammar, particle-が, particle-を

I've got a sentence which, I believe, has to be translated in Japanese using "Aの方がC" construction.

> Anna learns Japanese more (than for example English)

Can I translate it as 「アンナは日本語の方をたくさん勉強します」?

Or is it possible to write it this way: 「アンナは日本語の方がたくさんを勉強します」？

UPD: I might've misinterpreted the sentence due to wrong emphasis, since the original sentence is in Russian.

> **Anna** learns Japanese more (than somebody else)

So, basically, it is 「アンナの方が日本語をたくさん勉強します」

But what if the emphasis was on **Japanese**?

Comment: I'm fairly confused what you're trying to say when you say `what if the emphasis was on Japanese`

Comment: Let's see... Just imagine questions, e.g. A - "what language does Anna learn more, Japanese or English?" B - "Who learns Japanese more, Anna or Steve?" The reason you feel confused is probably messed up word order of those sentences. Sorry:))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> アンナは日本語の方をたくさん勉強します。

This sentence is fine.

> xアンナは日本語の方がたくさんを勉強します。

This sentence has two problems.

1. You have 日本語の方 as the subject (marked by が) of 勉強する, but it is not the **Japanese** that is doing the studying; it is Anna.
2. You have たくさん as the object (marked by を) of 勉強する, but Anna is studying **Japanese**. She is not studying たくさん.

> アンナの方が日本語をたくさん勉強します。

This sentence is fine.

You ask "But what if the emphasis was on Japanese?". I think you answered that with your first translation, didn't you?

Comment: Well... yes, I did. But I was not sure. Talking about the first sentence, I needed to know if it's possible (and allowed) to change が with を, since my book gave me the "Aの方がC" construction without mentioning that が can be changed by を. And now after I read your answer I can be sure that it's possible and legal. Also, I wasn't sure that this construction can be used when I want to emphasize different things, i.e. the doer and the object. Thank you for the answer.

Comment: -1: Any clues as to what I overlooked here would be appreciated. Thanks.